# Token allowance and locking compromised address

Tags: allowance

So i heard about token allowance checker https://tac.dappstar.io/. It allows you set allowance for tokens.

Is there a possible way to set the allowance so that your account wouldnt receive ethereum, or maybe like a time lock feature? Say ones account was compromised, could you stall it (lock it) so the unwanted party couldnt use said account?

Im completely green when it come to smart contracts.... could i write something like this for my account?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to block Ether reception. It is not possible to block ERC20 reception either.

A contract can be programmed to block ether transfer in the fallback function, so sending ether would cause a revert. There are methods that bypass that block, for example a contract that self-destruct can send its balance to any address bypassing the fallback function.